# How do I access subhash in MongoDB Ruby Driver?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

E.g. if I have documents with a field like this:

```
"time" : { "monday" : { "begin" : "00:00" }
```

and I want to find all the documents where "begin" equals to "00:00", in MongoDB built-in language I would type this:

```
db.COL.find({'time.monday.begin': "00:00"})
```

i.e. to access subelements I type the path fullstop-delimited in singe quotes. What would be the equivalent query in ruby driver? I tried different variations, including time["monday"]["begin"] and others, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do pretty much exactly the same thing with the ruby driver:

```
client.collection("foo").find("time.monday.begin" => "00:00")
```